# Can't understand how $\frac{1}{2}{ 2k+4 \choose k+2} = \frac{1}{2}(2k+4)!(k+2)!^2$ is correct

Tags: combinatorics

I'm following my teacher's notes and I cannot understand how $\frac{1}{2}{ 2k+4 \choose k+2} = \frac{1}{2}(2k+4)!(k+2)!^2$ is correct. Shouldn't it be $\frac{1}{2}{ 2k+4 \choose k+2} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{(2k+4)!}{(k+2)!^2}$ ?

Not sure if relevant, but the exercise (with which I don't need help with!) is to prove by induction ${0 \choose 0} + {2 \choose 1} + ... + {2n \choose n} < \frac{1}{2} {2n + 2 \choose n + 1}$ where $n \geqslant 2$.

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it should; looks like a misprint.

Comment: looks like a missing `\frac` command.

Comment: Well, you know, you don't have to ask an authority find out if this is correct or not.  Just try plugging in some different values for $k$ and test it yourself.

Comment: Yes of course $\frac{1}{2}{ 2k+4 \choose k+2} = \frac{1}{2}\frac{(2k+4)!}{(k+2)!^2}$

Comment: Because $\bigl(2k+4-(k+2)\bigr)!=(k+2)!$

Comment: @JairTaylor As much as I agree, when reading novel material many are much quicker to doubt their own understanding of it rather than to doubt the material at hand. And usually that is for the best, though sometimes not so as this question illustrates.

Comment: @Servaes Sure, I didn't mean to say the question was inappropriate.  But, as a general philosophy of learning, it is very helpful to keep a certain level of doubt when reading material and have the confidence to verify for yourself whether things make sense.  I usually find it more interesting to interact with the students willing to say "OMG THIS IS WRONG", even when it is not, than the ones who accept everything as a given but don't really understand.  Of course you can take this too far and become a crank too.

Comment: @JairTaylor I'm fairly new to combinatorics and I'd say maths in general. If I see something I think is incorrect, I wonder if I just don't know enough (which has been the case many times for me). My teacher tends to skip steps that seem obvious to him (but are not obvious to me), so I thought perhaps this was the case as well. It difficult to always doubt what I'm reading when I'm reading huge amounts of information and everything is new.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed by definition of the binomial coefficient
$$\frac{1}{2}\binom{2k+4}{k+2}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{(2k+4)!}{(k+2)!^2}.$$
Plugging in *any* value, for example simply $k=0$, shows that
$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{(2k+4)!}{(k+2)!(k+2)!}\neq\frac{1}{2}(2k+4)!(k+2)!^2,$$
so this is indeed a misprint as suggested in the comments.